# ifelse r - x and y lengths differ

Tags: r, if-statement, apply

I'm trying to use an `ifelse` on an array called "OutComes" but it's giving me some trouble.

```
>  PersonNumber Risk_Factor OC_Death OnsetAge Clinical CS_Death Cure AC_Death
>[1,]            1           1 99.69098       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
>[2,]            2           1 60.68009       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
>[3,]            3           0 88.67483       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
>[4,]            4           0 87.60846       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
>[5,]            5           0 78.23118       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
```

Now I will try to use an apply to analyse this table's `Risk_Factor` Column and apply one of two functions to replace the OnsetAge column's NA's.

I've been using an `apply` function -

```
apply(OutComes, 1, function(x)ifelse(OutComes[,"Risk_Factor"] == 1, 
                                      HighOnsetFunction(x), OnsetFunction(x))
```

However this obviously won't work as the ifelse itself won't work. the error being -

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

I'm not sure what's going on in this ifelse or what the x and y lengths are.

Comment: Functions `HighOnsetFunction` and  `OnsetFunction` . Can you share them as well?

Comment: Onsetfunction
    >function(x){unlist(approx(probability,age,x,ties=max)[2],use.names=F)}

High onset function is the same, just the probability table it uses is a higher.

Comment: *Not* as comment... better expand your initial request

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your apply function. You are applying a function with argument x (one row of OutComes), but then whithin ifelse, you use a vector OutComes[,"Risk_Factor"] which is a column of the original matrix, not a single number. One simple solution is to do

```
apply(OutComes, 1, function(x) ifelse(x["Risk_Factor"] == 1, 
                 HighOnsetFunction(x), OnsetFunction(x)))
```

But when dealing with a scalar, there is no real need to use ifelse, so it may be more efficient to write

```
apply(OutComes, 1, function(x) if (x["Risk_Factor"] == 1) HighOnsetFunction(x) else OnsetFunction(x)))
```

Comment: It's still throwing up the 
    >error in xy.coords(x,y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: Are you sure this is not an error in your [High]OnsetFunction ? Do they work OK if applied to one single row of your data?

Comment: I'll check, but the OnsetFunction is actually used earlier in the code with no difficulty. OC_Death column is generated using that onset function.

Comment: Does that mean they don't take as input one row of the data array (since you use the functions to define some columns), but something else? What is the actual input to these functions? If it is not a single row, maybe you shouldn't even be trying to use apply in this context?